# The Generalization of Bentley-Ottmann Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Bentley-Ottmann Algorithm is used to determined the intersection point of a list of lines. However as mentioned here [in Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm), there are a few drawbacks:

> The algorithm assumes that line
>   segments are not vertical, that line
>   segment endpoints do not lie on other
>   line segments, that crossings are
>   formed by only two line segments, and
>   that no two event points have the same
>   x-coordinate. However, these general
>   position assumptions are not
>   reasonable for most applications of
>   line segment intersection.

My question is is there a generalization of this algorithm can overcome/overcome the above difficulties?

Comment: I think you can handle all of those special cases by modifying the Bentley-Ottmann Algorithm. You will just lose a lot of the simplicity of the algorithm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Wikipedia article you linked to has a section on [handling these special positions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm#Special_position_and_numerical_precision_issues), which suggests these modifications to the basic algorithm:

- By convention, a point is to the "left" of a point vertically above it; thus the "left" endpoint of a vertical line is its *lower* endpoint.
- Events may consist of the crossings of two *or more* lines.
- When an event point is reached, its incident segments must be *reversed* in the sweep line (not just swapped, as there may be more than two).
- After a crossing is handled, there may be *more than two* old event points to be removed or *more than two* new event points to be inserted.

Answer (score 6):

These are the modifications to the algorithm proposed by Skanthak [here:](http://www.dike.de/~skanthak/university/cpsc516.pdf).

> The algorithm proceeds as follows: It ﬁrst creates events for all start- and endpoints of input segments.
>    It then handles all events in sorted order.
>    For each event, it fetches
>    the associated list *L* of segments starting at that point
>    and ﬁnds and removes all segments in the search tree
>    that intersect the current event point. 
>   It reports all those segments as intersections in that point. 
>   It then switches the order of the comparison function
>    by changing the ﬂag to be slightly after the current event. 
>   It reinserts all previously removed segments that
>    do not have their endpoint at the current event point
>    (because they have to be removed
>     from the structure at this point anyways)
>    and additionally insert the segments from *L*
>    (that are starting at this point). 
>   It checks the top and bottom neighbors
>    above and below the current event point for new intersections
>    and adds them as event points if it ﬁnds any.
>    This way the algorithm is robust
>    against all kinds of degeneracies,
>    including vertical segments and overlapping segments,
>    as well as segments intersecting on their endpoints.
>
> ```
> for all segments s do
>   Create events for the endpoints of s
> end for
> while event queue not empty do
>   Remove the smallest event point p from the queue
>   Let L be the set of segments that start at p
>   I ← all segments in the sweep line structure that contain p
>   remove I from sweep line structure
>   if |L| + |I| ≥ 2 then
>      Report intersections of L ∪ I
>   end if
>   C ← {s ∈ I | p is not endpoint of s}
>   Insert C in sweep line structure in reversed order
>   Check for new intersections among segments above and below p
> end while
> ```