# find the overlapping points of two series in devexpress chart

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, devexpress

As you can see , I have a winform chart ( DevExpress Chart ) with two series .
[image]
Each series has their points.
And what I want is to find the overlapping points of those two series ( pointed by green circle in picture ) .

For example ( 3.4 for the first overlapping point and 7.3 for the second overlapping point ) .
Thanks .

Comment: Can you share the values of all points in your series and create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: For the series with red color  { (4,A) (2,B) (10,C) (8,D) (6,E) (1,F)}
For the series with blue color { (0.5,A) (9.8,B) (5.5,C) (5.3,D) (2.5,E) (4.5,F)} .

Comment: But you can consider the argument (A,B,C,D,E,F) as number value (1,2,3,4,5,6) if you wish . For example

For the series with red color  { (4,1) (2,2) (10,3) (8,4) (6,5) (1,6)}
For the series with blue color { (0.5,1) (9.8,2) (5.5,4) (5.3,4) (2.5,5) (4.5,6)}

Comment: @zey are your points values randomly created or according to some type of mathematical function?

Comment: @zey as the c++ implementation requires CGAL functions maybe this link can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213117/the-generalization-of-bentley-ottmann-algorithm

Answer (score 5):

If you have direct access to the `Series` collection, you could:

`var intersection = Series[0].Points.Intersect(Series[1].Points);`

If you are creating discrete `Point` objects along the way, you may have to define the matching behavior, as well.

Comment: null value returned !

Comment: I think the OP asking for geometric intersection.

Comment: Exactly @nempoBu4 , I've search geometric intersection but I can't understand and I can't find perfect solution for my problem .

Answer (score 0):

As I understood each series in your case is just collection of sequantial points. All you need is to find intersection between line segments from each collection. I suggest to use for such purpose Bentley-Ottmann algorithm, which allows to find answer in (N log N) way (N is count of line segments from both series). Unfortunately I don't know whether there is implementation in c# (anytime you can use c++ implementation, if you will not find c# solution)

If you have always two series, defined by some two different functions, you can optimize algorithm in O (N) way (use "merge" logic)